# Port mirroring Vs. Network Sniffer?

Tags: networking, router, wireshark, sniffing

What's the difference between capturing the internet traffic using Port mirroring hub installed on router and simply running a Wireshark on the computer on which you want to capture the packets?

I have been using Wireshark for quite sometime on my computer to capture traffic and today I came across of some other capturing techniques like installing a Hub between the router and computer and using port mirroring. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Port mirroring allows you to do network sniffing.
Port mirroring refers to the concept of duplication traffic.
Network sniffing refers to the concept of paying attention to the packet's contents.  (An example could be to simply save a copy of packets that weren't necessarily being sent to you.)
A hub receives network traffic and essentially re-broadcasts a copy of whatever it received on all ports.
As technology improved, "dumb switches" became more common.  They typically improve network efficiency by only sending network traffic out the ports they need.  (The phrase "dumb switch" is also sometimes called an "unmanaged switch".)
"Port mirroring" may be the name that is often given to a feature implemented by a "smart switch" (also known as a "managed switch").
The difference between a dumb switch and a smart switch is that the smart switch may provide features that allow you to send traffic to the switch and to have the switch do something other than just re-broadcasting traffic, like allowing you to configure the switch to enable a "port mirroring" feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more in-depth look at capturing, I would highly recommend the 5-part "Network Capture Playbook" series, by Jasper Bongertz.  Jasper has done an excellent job in presenting the information in a concise but easy to understand format and does a far better job explaining everything than I could ever hope to do here.  So, if you're interested ...

1. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 1 - Ethernet Basics](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/10/the-network-capture-playbook-part-1-ethernet-basics/)
2. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 2 - Speed, Duplex and Drops](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/10/the-network-capture-playbook-part-2-speed-duplex-and-drops/)
3. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 3 - Network cards](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/11/the-network-capture-playbook-part-3-network-cards/)
4. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 4 - SPAN Port In-Depth](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/11/the-network-capture-playbook-part-4-span-port-in-depth/)
5. [The Network Capture Playbook Part 5 - Network TAP Basics](https://blog.packet-foo.com/2016/12/the-network-capture-playbook-part-5-network-tap-basics/)

You might also want to have a look at the Wireshark "[Ethernet capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet)" wiki page or visit the other [CaptureSetup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup) pages if you're interested in capture setups other than Ethernet, such as 802.11, PPP, etc.